# Dex error while running android Tests

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am working on android application,i am running test cases from androidTest folder where i added espresso and junit,i am getting dex error

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\MAINCODE\MAIN_id-android-sdk\predev\presdk\build\intermediates\multi-dex\androidTest\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\radha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0\jsr305-2.0.1.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-2.0.1.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class]))
Error:java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\MAINCODE\MAIN_id-android-sdk\predev\presdk-\build\intermediates\multi-dex\androidTest\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\radha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0\jsr305-2.0.1.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-2.0.1.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class]))
Error:java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\radha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0\jsr305-2.0.1.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-2.0.1.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class])
Error:java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-2.0.1.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class]
```

Comment: I'm running into this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add "exclude group" option on espresso dependencies :

```
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:$espresso_version", {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
})
androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso_version", {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
})
androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso_version", {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
})
```